# Starting an Elsa workflow from a Workflow model in a controller

Tags: c#, .net

I am planning to use Elsa workflow for an enterprise application with acceptance flow (State machine). I am not sure about this process:
I have multiple workflow models designed by admin user. Each is related to a different entity. Now in the corresponding api controller I want to start a workflow for the entity.
The question is which libraries to inject to controller and use to create and instance and get the created instance id?

i.e.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> StartFlowOfSomeEntity(int entityID)
{
   //Is it the right way to load registry?
   var registeryList = await _workflowRegistry.ListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
   var relatedRegistery = registeryList.FirstOrDefault(uu => uu.Name == "MyFlowName");
   //Now need to create new instance?   
}
```

I am using `UpdateInputAsync` of `WorkflowStorageService` to apply outputs to the workflow instance.

I tried to use IWorkflowInstanceStore as sugested [here](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/discussions/487) but could not achieve the goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkflowRegistery` is the right way to load models. But I prefer to use another method of it:

```
var relatedRegistery = await _workflowRegistry.FindByNameAsync("MyFlowName", VersionOptions.Latest);
```

For creating workflow instances you should inject WorkflowStarter to your controller and then do this:

```
RunWorkflowResult workflowInstance = await _wfStarter.StartWorkflowAsync(relatedRegistery , null, null, null, entityID.ToString());
```

Then `workflowInstance.WorkflowInstance.Id` has the value of the instance id you want.

You can also see [this](https://github.com/mzand111/MicroStruct) code at github doing similar thing with Elsa.

Comment: Thanks but the github project is not well documented. It would be more helpful if it has better documents.